# inotifywait does not work after running a period of time

Tags: inotifywait

I has running a daemon program to monitor a specific directory file changes, at the beginning, program is running normally, but after a period of time, inotifywait does work at the time of file changes. When i restart the program, it gets back to normal again. This is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
./etc/puppet/modules/config.sh
puppetmaster=`grep -w server ${puppet_config} | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`
/usr/local/bin/inotifywait -mrq -e modify ${log_dir}|  while read D E F
do
    /usr/bin/rsync -i -p -H -S -z -r -A -o -g -a --port=${port} \
    --timeout=600 --exclude='.svn/' --exclude='.git/' ${log_dir}/ \
    rsync://${puppetmaster}/log_dir > /dev/null
done
```

Please someone help me.Thanks..

Comment: Do you mean 'inotify does _not_ work at the time the file changes'?

Comment: Yes,but it works well at the beginning of the program startup.